# Wampserver : could not load file barimage.bmp specified in the directive Barpicturepicture

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I hope you'll help me..
I have an error message when I want to launch Wamp :  could not load file barimage.bmp specified in the directive Barpicturepicture.

The file is in C:/wamp64[files list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVHsK.png)

Thanks a lot for your help.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Did you install WAMPServer `as an administrator` ?

Comment: Did you install all the MSVC Runtime libraries as prompted to by the install?

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly. Thanks for your help.Yes, everything was ok, I have worked on a project before. I stopped in October and now, as I want to continue, I have this message.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message a few days back. In my case, I accidentally deleted all the three .bmp images (images_on.bmp, images_off.bmp and barimage.bmp) from the WAMP folder.

So I simply downloaded these images from [Github](https://github.com/phlyper/wamp-conf/tree/master/wamp).

Try this : Download all these images from the given link and replace them with the current images. Make sure that the extension is .bmp.

All the best!

Comment: Hi Jatin. Thanks a lot for your message. But I have all the files with the good extension .bmp. It doesn't work and I don't undestand..

Answer (score 0):

To anyone facing same issue, just go to wamp64 root folder and create files `barimage.bmp, images_on.bmp, images_off.bmp`. You can copy any other bmp file and rename as you wish to accomplish that.

I'm surprised the error is thrown right after upgrading wamp, and it's a package bug, but the above will solve the issue.